# Lotus Notes - Type ahead dropdown not working

Tags: lotus-notes

We use the IBM Notes 9.0.1 FP7 **basic** client on a Windows 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Server.

The type ahead function with dropdown list *should* look like this:
[image]

Some users complain that the type ahead **dropdown menu** stopped working all of a sudden (i.e. *"It worked this morning!"*)

The type ahead function itself works:

- If I start typing a name, it will auto-complete with the first entry it finds. 
  [image]
- When I type the beginning of a name and hit enter, it will show me a window with a list of found usernames that start with the same letters.

I'm unable to find how to re-enable the dropdown menu...or why it stopped working all together.